# Professor for a performance class is scheduling class time different than the class time listed in the catalog

Tags: graduate-school, undergraduate

I have a professor who is allotted 8 hours of time, 2 hours Monday/Friday and 4 hours Wednesday nights to rehearse the yearly opera. However, when we received the syllabus (halfway through the semester when the rehearsals began) we found that rehearsals were scheduled M-F nights and conflicted with numerous other things in the department as well as blindsiding our work schedules and etc. Is this allowed? I can't find any language in any handbook obligating the professor to teach in the times that they are scheduled by the registrar.

Comment: An abstract answer presumably won't help you.  Instead, if you decide to challenge this, you'll need to know the rules at your specific institution.  But first have you tried discussing it with your professor?  He might be clueless (and unaware of any hardship he is causing).

Comment: @EnergyNumbers That's a spectacularly unhelpful comment. One really shouldn't throw away all outside commitments on the whim of a professor who doesn't stick to her/his own schedule.

Comment: That being said, I don't understand the question. Is the "yearly opera" the class, or is singing in the opera your hobby which just happens to conflict with your class?

Comment: As a quick Google search shows, he's getting a degree in vocal performance, so it's a class. Is there any comment in the class description about 'times to be arranged?'

Comment: @EnergyNumbers if this was a student seeking a Master's in physiology and the professor teaching medical anatomy and wanted students to come in to the morgue M-F nights in addition to the 8 hours allocated, the same issue would apply. The subject of course study should not matter if it is an actual course, even if it were an elective.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers: It's quite likely that the opera is *part of* the asker's postgraduate degree.  Performing in a university's opera program would be routine, even expected, for a student studying for an MFA in vocal performance, for example.

Answer (score 3):

Performance groups, even when taken for credit, operate outside the "norms" of scheduling. It is unlikely that your concert will take place at the same time as your scheduled rehearsals, so you will need to make an "exception" to the rules just to participate in the performance—which is kind of the point of the class in the first place!

That said, the faculty member overseeing a performance class *does* need to be respectful of the schedule to the greatest extent possible. It is **not** fair to ask students to completely rearrange their schedules when alternatives are possible. If the faculty member does not believe there are enough scheduled hours to get things done, then there needs to be an adjustment in the course.

However, he will "get away" with this unless people make an issue of this. It sounds like there are a large number of people impacted. If so, then there is enough ground support that you can challenge it collectively without reprisal. (You can also "take it up the food chain" if the professor is unwilling to make changes.)

Comment: In professional and serious amateur theater companies, I believe the usual approach is that before rehearsal schedules are set, the key performers and crew are asked to submit a list of "conflicts", times when they are unavailable for rehearsal.  The director/producer then makes a rehearsal schedule, indicating which people are required to attend which rehearsals (it is generally not necessary for every performer to attend every rehearsal).  However, if someone has conflicts that the director can't work around, that person may be cut from the show and replaced by someone else.

Comment: I agree that it should have been made clear at the start of the class that there would likely be rehearsals outside of the scheduled class hours.  However, I think the most you can realistically expect at this point are minor tweaks in the rehearsal schedule - performance space will already have been booked, and so on.  An opera is usually a signature event for a music department, so they are unlikely to want to do anything that would seriously disrupt it.  You might achieve better advance notice for next year's class, but that's not much help at present.